# Python script running on server cannot successfully execute a GET request to a NASDAQ endpoint

Tags: python, api, request

I developed a script that needs to get the json data from this site:

https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/stocks?tableonly=true&offset=0&download=true

While developing this locally on my machine, this code works:

```
# gets all symbols from NYSE, NASDAQ, AMEX
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36",
    }

    res = requests.get("https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/stocks?tableonly=true&offset=0&download=true",
                       headers=headers)
```

However, as soon as I moved this code to a public server running Ubuntu 20.04, the request stopped working, and started indefinitely hanging. The request would not even return a response.

I tried using Chrome developer tools in order to copy the cURL request that my browser would make when accessing this API, and ran the pure curl command on the server, when doing this, the request succeeded and it returned the correct data. However, as soon as I broke apart the cURL command and put it into Python (and PHP) code, it would not work and would return to indefinitely hanging.

There are no outbound network rules defined on the server that I'm working on, nor any firewalls or IDS active. There's also no documentation regarding IP restrictions on the API or the like.

Update: I even tried the same script on an EC2 instance with a full copy of Windows 10 installed alongside Chrome (basically mimicking my local PC), and the request still hangs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you use Python or PHP on the server to successfully GET another page (e.g. google.com)?

Comment: @M.Zhang Yes, other trivial GET requests work

Answer (score 1):

Turns out NASDAQ has anti-scraping measures on their endpoints.

I'm assuming that their API allows requests from machines they declare to be personal, but not from servers, as their API is technically enterprise.

Solution to my issue was to buff up the headers to mock a call from a valid API user:

```
headers = {
    'authority': 'api.nasdaq.com',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36',
    'origin': 'https://www.nasdaq.com',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://www.nasdaq.com/',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}
```

Which successfully returns the desired information from the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let defaultHeaders = {}
defaultHeaders['accept'] = 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
defaultHeaders['accept-language'] = 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
defaultHeaders['sec-fetch-dest'] = 'empty',
defaultHeaders['sec-fetch-mode'] = 'cors',
defaultHeaders['sec-fetch-site'] = 'same-site',
defaultHeaders['user-agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
```

The important headers I had to add were probably the 3 sec-fetch-* headers